# How can I remove other data points based on the condition in multiple other columns in pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, if-statement

[I do not think this is a duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913659/pandas-conditional-creation-of-a-series-dataframe-column), as that question requires adding new data. I do not need to add new data, I need to select exisiting data based on a series of conditions.

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
signal,vaccine_dosage,vaccine_brand
10,0,Na
15,1,AZ
20,2,PF
30,3,AZ
10,0,Na
20,2,AZ
20,2,AZ
```

I need a new dataframe with only the 2 dosage signals from AZ. In R, I can do something like this:

```
file_input <- read.csv(file.choose())
two_dosage <- as.data.frame(
     as.numeric(ifelse(file_input$vaccine_dosage == 2 & 
     file_input$vaccine_brand == 'AZ', file_input$signal, NA)))
```

Which would give a dataframe like this:

```
signal
Na
Na
Na
Na
Na
20
20
```

I need to recreate this with Pandas, but I don't really know where to begin. How would you recreate this?

Comment: You want to write output as new data frame or add a output column to existing dataframe itself?

Answer (score -1):

Use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) with mask by [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv(file)
    
mask = pd.to_numeric(df['vaccine_dosage']).eq(2) & df['vaccine_brand'].eq('AZ')
df['signal'] = np.where(mask, df['signal'], np.nan)
```

Or with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[~mask, 'signal'] = np.nan
```